# How to delete nth character in a file using sed

Tags: linux, file-io, sed

I have to delete a character at nth position in a big file. `Vi` hangs for such a big file. I know there will be some simple command in `sed` to do so. But, I find it difficult to understand `sed` scripts and its expressions.

The file I have has content like:

> {"query": "Lock and", "timestamp": "2012-12-28T00:00:00.045000+00:00",
>   "productId": 322506},,{"query": "Velvet Crush", "timestamp":
>   "2012-12-28T00:00:00.045000+00:00", "productId": 134363}

I have to delete that extra `,` which is `130405` th character in that file. How do I use sed to achieve this.

EDIT:

Now I wish to replace all aoocurances of double comma by a single one in-place. How can that be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sed -i 's/.//130405' FILE`

This edits the file (`FILE`) in place (`-i`), deleting any character (`.`) at position `130405`

Comment: +1, I don't know why I came up a so awkward sed line.... after writing so many `s/foo/bar/1,2,3`, and forgot the `130405`!

Comment: How about removing all double occurances of comma in-place?

Answer (score 2):

Why `sed` when you have `cut`?

```
cut -c -130404,130406-
```

Comment: I don't see why this would not answer the question. `cut` is a perfect solution to the OPs problem of removing a number of chars from each line.

Answer (score 1):

Without even worrying about exactly where the double comma is, and assuming you want to fix *any* double comma throughout the file:

```
sed -e 's/,,/,/g' < file > file.new
mv file.new file
```

If you have a version of `sed` that supports it, you can `sed -i -e '...' file` to skip the redirections (but `sed -i` still essentially does exactly the same thing, just with a temporary file).

Comment: sed: couldn't re-allocate memory ..probably due to the size of the file

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do it in place with standard command line tools. A quick C/Python/whatever program to read the portions after the offending extra character and rewrite them one byte earlier wouldn't be too difficult, but unless you need to do this frequently, it's probably not really worth the effort...