# Create a text label with character-specific colors in ImageMagick

Tags: c++, image-processing, imagemagick, label, imagemagick-convert

I am doing some batch processing of some ASCII art, and currently have a C++ application that generates the art. I then run the text files through ImageMagick via the following command:

```
convert -font Courier \"label:@input.txt\" output.png
```

Finally, I combine the `.PNG` files into a single animated GIF via the following command:

```
convert *.png -set delay 100 MOVIE.GIF
```

What I would like to do is have all `#` characters be green, all `*` characters be red, etc, in the `.PNG` label files generated in the first step. How do I do this?

Additionally, is it possible to set the n'th character to a specific color rather than using a pattern like above? an example would be to draw the HSV spectrum or any arbitrary color pattern in paragraphs of text.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[sed](/questions/tagged/sed) is your friend for this. I would parse the file to extract each color channel, and adjust the [-fill](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#fill) flag

```sh
cat > input.txt <<EOF
#############
# * * * * * #
#* * * * * *#
#############
this is black
EOF
cat input.txt | sed 's/[\#\*]/ /g' > input.black.txt
cat input.txt | sed 's/[^\#]/ /g' > input.green.txt
cat input.txt | sed 's/[^\*]/ /g' > input.red.txt
convert -background transparent -font Courier \
        -fill black label:@input.black.txt \
        -fill green label:@input.green.txt \
        -fill red label:@input.red.txt \
        -flatten output.png
```

[image: Character-specific colors in ImageMagick]

I'm sure the above example can be simplified to a one-liner. And see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16404338/438117) for sed replace at nth character.

Comment: This is a very helpful and thorough answer. Thank you very much!